# How to publish only unique documents in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So I have mongodb collection with documents that some of them have the same key `(beatmapset_id)`:

```
{
    "_id" : "fgq7SK7LnLbcFzgSb",
    "beatmapset_id" : "59049",
    "version" : "Hard",
    "artist" : "UNDEAD CORPORATION",
    "title" : "Yoru Naku Usagi wa Yume wo Miru",
    "creator" : "Strawberry"
}
{
    "_id" : "u7M8wibPwxuStNLSM",
    "beatmapset_id" : "59049",
    "version" : "jom's Taiko Muzukashii",
    "artist" : "UNDEAD CORPORATION",
    "title" : "Yoru Naku Usagi wa Yume wo Miru",
    "creator" : "Strawberry"
}
{
    "_id" : "ChRwdj7kbPL7oYgty",
    "beatmapset_id" : "59049",
    "version" : "jom's Taiko Oni",
    "artist" : "UNDEAD CORPORATION",
    "title" : "Yoru Naku Usagi wa Yume wo Miru",
    "creator" : "Strawberry"
}
```

How do I publish only unique documents? Something like this:

```
Meteor.publish("beatmaps", function() {
  return Beatmaps.find({ beatmapset_id: 1 }, { unique: true });
});
```

Now i solve this having 2 collections. One with all documents and one where I removed those documents with this code:

```
db.beatmaps.ensureIndex({ beatmapset_id: 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups: true });
```

But it's slow and when my first collection updates I also need to update second as well. I'm sure it can be done more consistent way.